# Is it possible to obtain both the count and results of a query in a single MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on optimizing a MySQL query, and I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve both the count of the results and the actual result set in a single query. I'm aware that I can achieve this using separate queries, one for the count and one for fetching the results, but I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this within a single query.

Comment: is this a select or an update or something?  what client library are you using?

Comment: The query pertains to a SELECT statement. I'm utilizing Django to retrieve all records for a list API. Django typically employs two separate queries: one for fetching the records and another for obtaining the count of the records. I'm interested in exploring whether it's possible to consolidate these into a single query for improved efficiency.

Comment: please show an example query so we know what you are talking about.  most client library provide a way to get the number of rows without making a separate query, e.g. MySQLdb has result.num_rows()

Comment: I just realised I need the count of the query without the limit and offset and the results with the limit and offset :D. Would that be a problem?

Comment: are you using sql_calc_found_rows in your select?  please show us your query.

Comment: @ysth I don't have any particular query as such. Django will use two separate queries by default one for fetching the count and other for the actual paginated result. So what is shown in the front end is the paginated result of the total list of rows.

Comment: then show an example of the two queries

Comment: @AbdulRahman.  What is hard to understand that you need to post both existing queries for someone to help you?  If you have to, get a  'General Log' that includes both queries and post the TEXT of the General Log involved.

Comment: select Count(*) from ModelA & select a, b, c from ModelA limit 10 offset 10.
for joins
select Count(a) from ModelA left outer join ModelB; & select a,b,c , ModelB.d as d from ModelA left outer join ModelB limit 10 offset 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a subquery in SELECT :

`Select *, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM city) as total FROM city;`

And here is the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUsI8.png)

or in join case you can use this method :

```
SELECT COUNT(*),id,type_id FROM 
   ( 
         SELECT proprety.id,type.id as type_id
         FROM 
            proprety LEFT JOIN type
         ON proprety.type_id=type.id 

    ) as t1;
```

and here is the result :

[image]

Comment: whether this will be applicable to join queries as well ??

Comment: Yeah it works for sure but it depends on what you want to count for example in the example I showed you if I join the city table with another table we are still counting the number of cities as we did "(id) FROM city" it's up to you but yeah this works with JOIN.

Comment: Is it feasible to obtain the count of query results without limit and offset, and the results themselves with limit and offset, in a single MySQL query?

Comment: yeah in this case you can use this method (I'll add it the the main answer)

Comment: feasible?  sure.  performant?  not as likely, two separate queries can be much better.  but that does depend on the actual queries, and you haven't shown us examples

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the other order.

Rather than count the QuerySet size, then fetch it, you should instead fetch it and then determine length.

You can convert a QuerySet to a list. This fetches the query.

```
queryset_list = list(queryset)
```

Then `len()` on that list can be found without a query to the database.